# what is the difference between hardware overhead and software overhead when testing performance of an operating system

Tags: c++, performance, hardware, overhead

I am doing a school project for an operating systems class. I have to estimate various overheads - for example, time measurement overhead, context switch overhead, memory/disk access overhead.  In several of these contexts, I am required to estimate what the software overhead component of the overhead will be, and what the hardware component will be.  Could somebody provide an example of what operations would be characterized as hardware overhead and what operations would be software?  Am I correct in assuming that setting up the stack when a function is called is software overhead because it only involves pointers being moved?  Accessing a block on disk would be hardware overhead?  These operations seem simple to characterize.  Perhaps somebody could give some other examples to firm up my understanding.

Comment: Clear questions (not asking for vague examples). More paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever gave you the assignment should have defined the terms involved, such as `software overhead` or `hardware component`. If they did not, you should ask.

It's not as clear cut as it may look. You seem to accept that `Accessing a block on disk would be hardware overhead`. How about memory, then? Memory is a hardware component, just as a hard drive is. Each memory access requires a measurable, albeit tiny, time. Is that to be factored into the software vs. hardware counts? And that's before even talking about pipes, caches, or virtual memory page faults which can translate into disk access.

I could make similar points about network, GPU, monitor and so on. Main point remains, however, that for an assignment it's always better to ask, than to second guess - and possibly guess wrong.

Answer (score 1):

These are correct examples. Some other examples of hardware overheads include waiting for a device (e.g. printer), and waiting for another node on a network.

A software overhead may be accessing a shared library, as are virtual tables. You'll be hard pressed to find either in kernel space; I don't think shared objects can exist outside of user land.